# Receive an image by c# that sent by Java(android)

Tags: java, c#, android

I have a problem with images in java/c#.
I want to send an image from my android device and receive it to my c# application.
Here is my android code:

```
private void sendVideo(ByteArrayOutputStream rawImage)
    {
        byte[] byteArray2 = rawImage.toByteArray();
        byte[] byteArray;
        String test = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray2, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byteArray = test.getBytes();
        String metaData = String.valueOf(clientID)+String.valueOf(videoCounter);
        byte[] metaDataBuff = metaData.getBytes();
        if (UDP) {
            udpBuffSend = new byte[60000];
            System.arraycopy(metaDataBuff, 0, udpBuffSend, 0, 8);
            System.arraycopy(byteArray, 0, udpBuffSend, 8, byteArray.length);
```

and here is my c# code:

```
string Base64ImageData = Convert.ToBase64String(udpBuff, 8, udpBuff.Length - 8);
                            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64ImageData);
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                            imageBytes.Length);

                           ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                           masterPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);
```

but it is throwing an exception "Invalid argument".
What is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try if something like this works:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64ImageData);
Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
masterPicture.Image = image;
```